# Using Flutter Intl with constants without a context to reference

Tags: flutter, localization

I've been implementing localization for all my strings in my app (following this guide https://appunite.com/blog/how-to-localize-flutter-app) and was able to get all the areas inside widgets where there is a BuildContext.  But I have a constants file with some lists (that I use for select options) and want to localize the options as well.  But the file just has constants and no BuildContext.  So cant do `S.of(context).enterAValue`.  Not sure how to approach this

Answer (score 3):

Regarding referencing translation without context, there is already [opened issue](https://github.com/localizely/flutter-intl-intellij/issues/4) for Flutter Intl plugin.

As an alternative, maybe the usage of **Select ICU format** kind of messages can help you to localize select options.

Message example:

```
"selectOptions": "{choice, select, opt_one {Option 1} opt_two {Option 2} other {None}}"
```

Usage example:

```
final optionOne = 'opt_one';

S.of(context).selectOptions(optionOne)
```